# Use JQuery to show loading message when clicking on any a tag

Tags: jquery

The site's pages contain regular `<a>` tags, some have a class definition which is used for CSS.
Every `<a>` has a `href=""` definition to some other page on the site.
Want I want is that whenever any `<a>` on the page is clicked, jQuery will show a loading message.

This is what I have for jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#loading").show("fast");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't cause the `#loading` div to show whenever a `<a>` tag is clicked. The site starts loading the defined `href=""` and after about 20 seconds the requested page is shown.
Since the site retrieves a large amount of data from an external database the loading of the pages takes between 5 and 30 seconds. And I wish to notify the viewer about this loading time by showing the `#loading` div.

Comment: Hi, what is your HTML code for the #loading div? With CSS please.

Comment: Your code looks fine, the problem is caused by how the browser handles these clicks and has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.
The jQuery was fine, the html and CSS were not the problem.
The problem was (and this is really dumb) I forgot to load the .js file into the html page.

I added `<script src="./view/jquery/clickload.js"></script>` to my layout page and it worked perfectly. It was a stupid mistake.